# Remove message textarea as required element in "send to friend" form

Tags: forms, validation, magento

i am using Magento 1.5.1.0. I want to remove the "message" textarea as an required field
in the "send to friend" form. Where can i change this behaviour?

Regards,
Bertie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is hardcoded (magento community edition). You have to overwrite the validate method